# How do I implement a rounded blurred raised button in a bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a custom navigation bar that resides on the bottom of the application. This navigation bar contains tricks that I'm not well aware with.

Here is the desired shape of the navigation bar.

[image: Desired Navigation Bar]

The tricks of this bar that I face is:

1. The blurring against a dynamic ImageView that comes from a server and changes frequently.
2. The middle circle that contains the camera image and the transparent stroke color of that circle.

I've managed to solve the first problem by using [AnndBlur](https://github.com/harism/android_anndblur) library, that provides layouts that blurs automatically with the background.

Unfortunately I'm facing problems in dealing with the middle camera button and the transparent stroke color.

Here is the latest view that I'm working on

[image: Latest outcome]

Here is the code of the bottom nav bar layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_bottom_toolbar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_take_photo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/landing_bottom_toolbar_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_bottom_toolbar_height"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

    <com.myapp.view.blur.BlurLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_bottom_inner_toolbar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:radius="10dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_my_profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_schedule"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_contacts"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contacts" />
    </com.myapp.view.blur.BlurLinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or guidelines would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Thanks Machinarius comment made the camera icon level to be above the other buttons, now the latest toolbar shape :

[image: Updated Toolbar]

But still need to figure out the rounded circle with transparent stroke color

Comment: Put the imageView below the blur layout, it should work if RelativeLayout behaves like a FrameLayout in that regard. If not, swap out the RelativeLayout for a FrameLayout for the same effect with slightly increased layouting performance.

Comment: Great! that made the Camera icon to be above the toolbar, but still the problem of the rounded blurred background with the transparent stroke color. I tried playing with the canvas and setXferMode using CLEAR PorterDuffMode but it didn't work

Comment: I can't help you there as i have no experience with those kinds of layouting tricks. Seems to me that a couple pre-rendered blurred 9Patches would make your life way easier though.

Comment: http://android-devblog.blogspot.it/2010/08/rounding-picture.html

Comment: @Der Golem I tried using PorterDuff different modes, but all I can see a black stroke not a transparent one.

Comment: @Machinarius I thought of using 9Patch but I think that it might not suit my needs as the background has to be blurred, I might be wrong though

Comment: A semi transparent png with white blur *could* work